# Cannot scrape web page properly because of encoding issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, encoding, request

Although I set the encoding to detect Turkish characters, it does not capture and display properly this web page. It does work for all other pages similar to this one which is under the same charset and domain. I could not understand why it happens? Any idea ? Thanks in advance!

For instance:

> Bilgisayar MÃ¼hendisliÄŸi BÃ¶lÃ¼mÃ¼

rather than:

> Bilgisayar Mühendisliği Bölümü

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://bmb.osmaniye.edu.tr/personel-akademik"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf-8")

print(soup.original_encoding)
print(soup)
```

The output:

```
windows-1252
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en"><head>
<title>Osmaniye Korkut Ata Ãœniversitesi - Bilgisayar MÃ¼hendisliÄŸi BÃ¶lÃ¼mÃ¼</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<!-------------<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1254" />---------------->
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="" name="google-site-verification">
<meta content=",Bilgisayar MÃ¼hendisliÄŸi BÃ¶lÃ¼mÃ¼" name="keywords"/>
```

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content.decode('utf-8','backslashreplace'), 'html.parser')` could help?

Comment: @JosefZ it does work perfectly, but i do not understand the point! Could you suggest me documentation what is going on this issue? In addition, why setting the encoding as utf-8 cannot handle the job in my code? How can you spot the point because I am assuming that you are not familiar with the mentioned language? Is it by comparison of ASCII values of both outputs? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

For your future web-scraping endeavors, you might want to try with this first:

`page.encoding = page.apparent_encoding`

or, as suggested, decoding with backslash replacement.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://bmb.osmaniye.edu.tr/personel-akademik")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content.decode("utf-8", "backslashreplace"), 'html.parser').find("title").getText(strip=True)
print(soup)
```

Gives you this:

```
Osmaniye Korkut Ata Üniversitesi - Bilgisayar Mühendisliği Bölümü
```

Comment: As @JosefZ suggests, his solution does work but the solution you offer about .encoding does not work. By the way, i have already tried that before i ask the question here because the aim is not only read title of the page, i need to scrape entire content and characters properly.